Why does the soap library not insert all xlmns?
There was a problem.
I was given a very bad wsdl file.
I am using the soap library on node js. Here's the code.
const apiUrl = './kodos.wsdl';

var wsdlOptions = {
  attributesKey: '$attributes',
};
soap.createClient(apiUrl, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
      console.error('Error creating SOAP client:', err);
      return;
  }
  console.log(client['wsdl']['xmlnsInEnvelope'])
  const login = {
    name: {
      $attributes: {
        "xsi:type": 'xsd:string'
      },
      $value: 'admin'
    },
    password: {
      $attributes: {
        "xsi:type": 'xsd:string'
      },
      $value: '17AA8AC8C7FB4221B41F731EDA809AC67DE69DA85AEDBD38D6469EECDD73D213'
    },
  }
  client.Login(login, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error making SOAP request:', err);
        return;
      }
    })
});

(I attach a screenshot) as a result, when I send a request,
for some reason half of the xlmns are not registered in the envelope wsdl file picture
In the wsdl -
in the post request when executing client.
Login -
soap library generating
The developers sent me what request should be sent in order for everything to work. Here it is.
working code
As you can see, xlmns in the request is more than the soap library generates. Why is this happening?Can you tell me where what's wrong? What did I miss? Maybe I misunderstood the logic?
I have already started rewriting the wsdl file.
But unfortunately I don't know much about the subtleties.
I tried it through chatgpt, but he writes that everything is fine,
everything should work. I've tried other libraries.
In any library, the number of xlmns is determined correctly,
but not all are included in the request.

Welcome to SO. Please avoid inserting images of text, and instead include the code snippets directly in your post. Refer to how-to-ask for more details.
